# Cheapest available positional tracking VR headset

Tags: vr-headset

There are currently three main tiers of virtual reality headsets on the market:

- At the low end, there are Google Cardboard-style headsets, made out of either cardboard or plastic that you can get for as low as a dollar.  They work with essentially all smartphones, but they only feature rotational tracking, not positional tracking.  And they don't have a VR operating system, so you have to first navigate to the VR app you want and then put the headset on.
- There are medium-tier devices, specifically the Samsung Gear VR headset and the Google Daydream View headset, that you can get for about $100.  They too only feature rotational tracking, and they're limited to one specific smartphone, but they have a whole built-in VR operating system you can explore VR apps within.
- At the high-end, there are headsets like the Oculus Rift and HTC Vivek, that generally cost $1000 or more once you take into account the price of the gaming PC you have to tether the headset to.  They feature both rotational tracking and positional tracking.

My question is, what is the cheapest VR headset you can buy that has positional tracking?  I want the cost to take into account the price of e gaming PC if you need one to use it.  But if it's smartphone-based, there's no need to take into account the price of the smartphone.

So far the cheapest one I've found is the [Occipital Bridge](https://bridge.occipital.com), which is $400, only works with iPhones, and does not require a gaming PC.  It's available for pre-order know and ships in mid-May.

There's also the Acer headset which will release by the end of the year, and which is supposed to cost only $300.   And then there are the inside-out VR headsets under development listed in the end of my question [here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/6709/5445).  But does anyone know the cheapest product that's available right now?